# QuerySet caching: executing get after filter was fired

Tags: python, database, django, caching, django-queryset

How many database queries will be executed for the following code:

```
q = SomeModel.objects.filter(pk__in=ids)
print q    # The actual query is executed and the result 
           # set evaluated
m = q.get(pk=ids[0])
print m    # Does it reuse the evaluated result set 
           # or does it hit the database the second time?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since querysets are evaluated lazily if you do:

```
q = SomeModel.objects.filter(pk__in=ids)
```

...immediately folllowed by (i.e., without using `print`):

```
m = q.get(pk=ids[0])
```

You'll end up with one SQL query. It'll `AND` together the first query with the second. It's safe to continue adding to querysets this way. In Django 1.3 the logging is revamped and you can get nice logging in the interactive console:

```
>>> import logging
>>> l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
>>> l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

Which will give you this sort of debugging info as soon as an actual query is executed:

```
(0.013) SELECT "someapp_somemodel"."id", "someapp_somemodel"."question", "someapp_somemodel"."pub_date" FROM "someapp_somemodel" WHERE ("someapp_somemodel"."id" IN (0, 1) AND "someapp_somemodel"."id" = 0 ); args=(0, 1, 0)
```

Don't use `get` on a filtered queryset. If the model you want is in your queryset, use a Python expression (like a list comprehension or `filter` or such) to get the model instance out of your queryset, and avoid hitting the database at all a second time (or many more times if you iterate over a list of id's).

Comment: Note that those `print`s in the mean time simulate the evaluation of the result set. It's not my actual code, it just serves as a minimalistic example. I'm specifically interested in the described situation where `filter` and `get` are separated by evaluation of the first query set.

Comment: @julkiewicz just use a python expression to get the model instance you want. You can for instance do `filter(lambda x: x.id == 3, qs)` and get the model instance with `id == 3`, without hitting the database again. Turn on the logging in the console and experiment, and you'll see when/how queries are executed in your specific case, and be able to refine your approach.